# Compiling SQL procedures in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, angular9

I have built an SQL editor using Angular and I am using Spring Boot and MySQL for backend. Now I would like to compile the procedure that I write in my SQL editor. Is there a way to compile the procedure I send from Angular in Spring Boot?

Comment: You don't need to compile it

Comment: Okay, then is there a way to execute in Spring Boot?

Comment: Sure via JDBC. I don't understand your question. Do you know JDBC?

Comment: When we have a procedure that is already compiled in the database, we can execute it in spring boot by calling the procedure name. But in my case, the procedure is dynamic. I would need to have the procedures created in the editor and store them in database which I may reuse later. So if I may not need to compile it, how could I be able to execute it. Is there any specific class that JDBC provides. I tried with jdbcTemplate, it didnt work. So is there any approach?

Comment: Or am I approaching my requirement in a wrong way? If so is there any other way to store the dynamic procedure and call them whenever  needed?

Comment: You have to execute create procedure via JDBC

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I will check on that.

Comment: As far as I searched, there is no way of creating procedure via JDBC. Also I tried to get a way for executing an anonymous block. But again JDBC does not support that. I am helpless now.